# When I try onCreate the CREATE_USER_TABLE got error

Tags: android, database, sqlite

//this is my DatabaseHelper.java

```
CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_USER + "(" + COLUMN_USER_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_USER_NAME + "TEXT," + COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + "TEXT," + COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + "TEXT," + ")";

private String DROP_USER_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_USER;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL(DROP_USER_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void addUser(User user) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_USER_NAME, user.getName());
    values.put(COLUMN_USER_EMAIL, user.getEmail());
    values.put(COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD, user.getPassword());

    db.insert(TABLE_USER, null, values);
    db.close();
}

public boolean checkUser(String email, String password) {
    String[] columns = {
            COLUMN_USER_ID
    };
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    String selection = COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " = ?" + " AND " + COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + "=?";
    String[] selectionArgs = {email,password};

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER,
            columns,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            null,
            null,
            null);
    int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    if (cursorCount > 0){
        return  true;
    }
    return false;
}`
```

Comment: Have you looked into Room android architecture component? Here's a link to Room:  https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room

This Room persistence library is built on SQLite and makes it very easy to turn your classes into tables for SQLite. It can also generate a lot of needed SQL instructions on your behalf making it easy and error free. Give it a try. Here's the official video on it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SKWh4ckvFPM

Answer (score 0):

You don't post what the error is but, looking at your code, I can see one major problem.

What one needs to keep in mind is that SQLite relies on appropriate spaces in its statements. So, your statement

```
CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_USER + "(" + 
COLUMN_USER_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_USER_NAME + "TEXT," + COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + "TEXT," + COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + "TEXT," + ")";
```

will translate to something like

```
CREATE user_table useridINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,user_nameTEXTuser_emailTEXT,user_passwordTEXT,)
```

See the problem? Spaces are not where they need to be. You will need to produce a statement something like this:

```
CREATE user_table, userid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT,user_name TEXT, user_email TEXT, user_password TEXT
```

to get the spaces inserted in the right way.

Do a logcat print to see the statement you are producing so you can make adjustments.